# Ассемблер. Перевод числа в строку

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Хотелось бы разобраться, каков алгоритм перевода числа в строку для очень больших чисел, например такого: 10000000000, и больше. Коды, которые находил на просторах сети, малопонятны. Объясните, пожалуйста, доступным языком новичку.

код библиотеки

```
format MS COFF

section '.data' data readable writeable
buffer dq 0

public my_proc as '_my_proc'

section '.text' code readable executable

proc my_proc c num, str     ;процедура cdecl с использованием макросов

start:
push ebx
xor eax, eax            ;очищение регистра
mov edi, [str]          ;заносим адрес строки в регистр
mov eax, [num]          ;заносим число в регистр для дальнейшего деления
test eax, eax           ;проверка знака числа в EAX
jns unum_to_str         ;переход, если число без знака или равно нулю
mov byte[edi], '-'      ;добавление знака в начало строки
inc edi
neg eax             ;инвертирование двоичного числа в EAX (дополнительный        код и прочее)

;Преобразование беззнакового числа
unum_to_str:
    xor ecx, ecx        ;обнуление счетчика
    mov ebx, 10     ;помещаем в регистр EBX делитель
    cycle1:
    xor edx, edx        ;обнуление старшей части двойного слова (остатка)
    div ebx         ;деление (EDX:EAX)/EBX, остаток в EDX
    add edx, 30h        ;Преобразование остатка в код символа
    push edx        ;сохраняем остаток в стеке
    inc ecx         ;увеличиваем счетчик цикла (для второго цикла)  
    test eax, eax       ;проверка EAX
    jnz cycle1      ;переход к началу цикла, если частное не ноль

cycle2:
    pop edx         ;восстановление символа из стека
    mov [edi], edx      ;сохранение символа в строку
    inc edi         ;увеличиваем адрес строки
    loop cycle2     ;цикл продолжается, пока ECX>0

;Восстановление из стека
pop ebx
ret
endp
```

код на си++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
unsigned int my_proc(unsigned int, char*);
}

void main()
{
char str[250]="";
unsigned int num;

cout << "Input number: ";
scanf("%d", &num);
my_proc(num, str);

cout << "Number to string: " << str <<endl;

_getch();
}
```

Comment: Вам для практики (например, через вызов функции sprintf) или нужен общий алгоритм перевода числа в строковую форму в десятичной системе?

Comment: В целом, общий. Хотя и на практике его реализовать надо, но как внешнюю процедуру для ЯВУ, @insolor

Comment: Тогда еще вопрос: насколько большие числа вам нужны? В double можно хранить числа с точностью до целого до 2 в 53 степени. Если нужно больше, то это уже что-то вроде big integer, который нужно реализовывать отдельно, я бы на ассемблере это делать не взялся. Общий алгоритм - делить число на 10 с остатком, к остатку прибавлять символ '0' (фактически, его код) и записывать куда-то справа налево, частное опять делить с остатком, и так пока оно не обратится в 0.

Comment: Вот, о таком алгоритме знаю, он понятен. В своей процедуре число, введенное пользователем, передаю в регистр eax, далее делю на 10 и так далее, как Вы и сказали. Но при вводе числа с 9 нулями? например, то же 10000000000, выводится совсем не ожидаемый результат. Как можно решить эту проблему?@insolor

Comment: @insolor числа целые. Дословно задача состоит в том, чтобы перевести n-битное целое число в строку

Comment: Если вы знаете как переводить числа в другую систему счисления, то вы можете применить этот алгоритм здесь. Разница только в том, что для нас более привычная десятичная система, а для процессора двоичная

Comment: В int (4 байта) помещается целое знаковое число ориентировочно до 2 миллиардов или беззнаковое до 4. 10 миллиардов еще на этапе ввода превратятся в какое-нибудь "левое" число, проблема тут не в процедуре вывода, а в максимальной "емкости". Вообще, делением в строку можно переводить и большие числа: div же делит пару регистров edx:eax, а это целых 8 байт. Так что задача скорее в том, чтобы первоначально использовать для хранения числа 8 байт, а не в 4.

Comment: @insolor тогда вот проблема. при вводе числа 4 294 967 295 выдает тоже какое то "левое" число. хотя тип стоит unsigned int. как это исправить?

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос.

Comment: @insolor готово

Comment: Сначала бился над нормальной компиляцией кода на C++ и кода на ассемблере, потом плюнул и скомпилировал вашу библиотеку в отдельный исполняемый файл. При 4294967295 она возвращает -1, что в принципе верно.

Comment: Нашел бажек: функция должна сохранять edi (по соглашению cdecl). Пока не добавил сохранение этого регистра в функцию, функция затирала сохраненный в edi адрес буфера, и вызывающая функция выводила на экран не содержимое буфера str, а пустую строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходная процедура на ассемблере корректна, за исключением того, что по соглашению `cdecl` она должна сохранять и регистр `edi`. Ну и входное число оно воспринимает как знаковое.

Переписал процедуру так, чтобы она принимала на вход адрес 64-битного беззнакового целого. Ниже код процедуры вместе с тестирующим кодом:

```
include 'win32ax.inc'

.data
    buf rb 250
    num dq 10000000000000

.code

proc my_proc c uses ebx esi edi, pnum, buf
    ; (параметры передаются по соглашению cdecl, три регистра сохраняются в стеке)
    xor ecx, ecx  ; обнуление счетчика
    xor edx, edx
    mov ebx, 10  ; помещаем в регистр EBX делитель

    mov esi, [pnum]  ; заносим адрес исходного числа в регистр
    mov edi, [esi+4]  ; старший dword
    mov esi, [esi+0]  ; младший dword

    test edi, edi
    jz .loop_low

.loop_high:
    ; Делим старший dword
    mov eax, edi
    div ebx
    mov edi, eax
    ; в edx - остаток от деления

.loop_low:
    ; Делим остаток от деления старшего dword-а и младший dword
    mov eax, esi
    div ebx
    add edx, '0'
    push edx ; код символа - в стек
    inc ecx
    mov esi, eax
    xor edx, edx

    test edi, edi ; проверяем, не равна ли старшая часть нулю
    jnz .loop_high

    test eax, eax ; проверяем, не равна ли младшая часть нулю
    jnz .loop_low

    ; Считываем символы из стека в буфер
    mov edi, [buf]
@@:
    pop edx
    mov [edi], edx
    inc edi
    dec ecx
    jnz @b

    ret
endp

start:
    push buf
    push num  ; адрес числа
    call my_proc
    add esp, 8

    invoke MessageBox, 0, buf, 'Result', 0
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

.end start
```

Результат выполнения:

[image: Скриншот]