# Помогите перевести код с fasm на nasm

Tags: ассемблер, fasm, nasm

Мне нужно вывести текущее время в терминал пишу код на `nasm`. Для перевода числа в строку решил использовать [этот код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476189/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83).

Он написан на `fasm` и оформлен в отдельную процидуру. Я же хочу использовать его в теле моей программмы. Мне непонятна пара моментов:
Что такое `@@` и `@b` в том коде? В остальном же, мне кажется, я понял суть прогрммы и написал правильный код:

```
  section .bss
  buf resb 250 

  section .text
  global _start
  gettime:

  mov eax, 13
  xor ebx, ebx

  int 0x80

  mov [time], eax ; время в секундах, перевести в строку для вывода

  ; перевод 

   xor ecx, ecx ; 0 в счетчик
   xor edx, edx ; 0

   mov ebx, 10 ; делитель системы счисления

   mov esi, [time]

   mov edi, [esi+4] ; старший dword
   mov esi, [esi+0] ; младший dword

   test edi, edi ; меняем флаги

   jz lowdword

   hightdword:

   ; делим старший dword

   mov eax, edi 
   div ebx
   mov edi, eax

   ; остаток от деления в edx

   lowdword:
   ; делим остаток от деления и младший dword

   mov eax, esi
   div ebx
   add edx, '0'
   push edx ; код символа в стек

   inc ecx
   mov esi, eax
   xor edx, edx

   test edi, edi ; Старшая часть не равна нулю

   jnz hightdword

   test eax, eax ; Младшая часть не равна нулю
   jnz lowdword

   mov edi, [buf]
   ; Дальше идёт метка @@

   ; теперь строка на вывод

   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, buf
   mov edx, 8


   int 0x80
```

Чем можно заменить `@b` и что это за команда?

Comment: `@@` — это анонимная метка... `@b` — ближайшая анонимная метка сзади... заменить можно на обычные локальные метки...

Answer (score 1):

`@@` - это анонимные метки. Переход на `@b` или `@r` - это переход на ближайшую предыдущую метку `@@`, переход на `@f` - на ближайшую следующую ([документация](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#1.2.3)). Это не специфично именно для fasm, такой вариант меток есть и в masm, например.

Можно заменить на обычные метки:

```
    ; Считываем символы из стека в буфер
    mov edi, [buf]
loop_start:
    pop edx
    mov [edi], edx
    inc edi
    dec ecx
    jnz loop_start
```

Не знаю зачем вы в коде заменили локальные метки (с точкой в начале) на обычные - такие метки в nasm поддерживаются (см. тут например: [Локальные метки](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/nasm/nasm_ru3.html#section-3.8))

Comment: @insotor Вывода почему-то не происходит...

Comment: Начнем с того, что код из ответа, который вы пытаетесь применить, предназначен для превращения в строку 64-битного целого числа, а вам нужно перекодировать всего лишь 32-битное. Вам нужен более простой код. За основу можно взять пример "Вывод чисел в десятичном виде" отсюда (сайт умер, поэтому ссылка на архив), только все регистры кроме dl заменить на 32-битные: [Вывод чисел на консоль](https://web.archive.org/web/20180901113638/http://asmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/022-vyvod-chisel-na-konsol/)